# Implementing AES encrypt and decrypt using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, encryption, cryptography

In my web application I am asking user to upload the files. I am reading that file and converting it into byte array like this

```
 byte[] fileContent =new byte[(int)uploadedFile.length()];
 FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(uploadedFile);
 fin.read(fileContent);
```

Now I encrypt this byte array using AES encryption with the password supplies by the user. I am using [this library](http://www.aescrypt.com/) to encrypt. After encryption I am saving this byte array into hibernate database. I have this filed in my Files entity class.

```
@Lob
@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@Column(name = "filedata", columnDefinition = "LONGBLOB")
private byte[] fileData;
```

I am saving this by save method

```
    session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(f);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
```

When I retrive the file from database I use get method

```
    session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    cr=session.createCriteria(Files.class);
    Files f=(Files) cr.add(Restrictions.eq("fid", fid)).uniqueResult();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
```

After retrieving I am decrypting the byte array that is in the File object but I am getting Input file is corrupt error. I understand this error is because the byte array has changed from saving to getting.

What would be the solution to this issue. I want the user to supply password for encrypting and decrypting. I am using MySql database at the backend.

EDITS: AESCrypt class

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

/**
 * This class provides methods to encrypt and decrypt files using
 * <a href="http://www.aescrypt.com/aes_file_format.html">aescrypt file format</a>,
 * version 1 or 2.
 * <p>
 * Requires Java 6 and <a href="http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp">Java
 * Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files</a>.
 * <p>
 * Thread-safety and sharing: this class is not thread-safe.<br>
 * <tt>AESCrypt</tt> objects can be used as Commands (create, use once and dispose),
 * or reused to perform multiple operations (not concurrently though).
 *
 */

@Repository
public final class AESCrypt {
    private static final String JCE_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE = "Please make sure "
        + "\"Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files\" "
        + "(http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp) is installed on your JRE.";
    private static final String RANDOM_ALG = "SHA1PRNG";
    private static final String DIGEST_ALG = "SHA-256";
    private static final String HMAC_ALG = "HmacSHA256";
    private static final String CRYPT_ALG = "AES";
    private static final String CRYPT_TRANS = "AES/CBC/NoPadding";
    private static final byte[] DEFAULT_MAC =
        {0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, (byte) 0x89, (byte) 0xab, (byte) 0xcd, (byte) 0xef};
    private static final int KEY_SIZE = 32;
    private static final int BLOCK_SIZE = 16;
    private static final int SHA_SIZE = 32;

    private final boolean DEBUG;
    private byte[] password;
    private Cipher cipher;
    private Mac hmac;
    private SecureRandom random;
    private MessageDigest digest;
    private IvParameterSpec ivSpec1;
    private SecretKeySpec aesKey1;
    private IvParameterSpec ivSpec2;
    private SecretKeySpec aesKey2;


    /*******************
     * PRIVATE METHODS *
     *******************/


    /**
     * Prints a debug message on standard output if DEBUG mode is turned on.
     * @param message
     */
    protected void debug(String message) {
        if (DEBUG) {
            System.out.println("[DEBUG] " + message);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Prints a debug message on standard output if DEBUG mode is turned on.
     * @param message
     * @param bytes
     */
    protected void debug(String message, byte[] bytes) {
        if (DEBUG) {
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder("[DEBUG] ");
            buffer.append(message);
            buffer.append("[");
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
                buffer.append(bytes[i]);
                buffer.append(i < bytes.length - 1 ? ", " : "]");
            }
            System.out.println(buffer.toString());
        }
    }


    /**
     * Generates a pseudo-random byte array.
     * @param len
     * @return pseudo-random byte array of <tt>len</tt> bytes.
     */
    protected byte[] generateRandomBytes(int len) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[len];
        random.nextBytes(bytes);
        return bytes;
    }


    /**
     * SHA256 digest over given byte array and random bytes.<br>
     * <tt>bytes.length</tt> * <tt>num</tt> random bytes are added to the digest.
     * <p>
     * The generated hash is saved back to the original byte array.<br>
     * Maximum array size is {@link #SHA_SIZE} bytes.
     * @param bytes
     * @param num
     */
    protected void digestRandomBytes(byte[] bytes, int num) {
        assert bytes.length <= SHA_SIZE;

        digest.reset();
        digest.update(bytes);
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            random.nextBytes(bytes);
            digest.update(bytes);
        }
        System.arraycopy(digest.digest(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    }


    /**
     * Generates a pseudo-random IV based on time and this computer's MAC.
     * <p>
     * This IV is used to crypt IV 2 and AES key 2 in the file.
     * @return IV.
     */
    protected byte[] generateIv1() {
        byte[] iv = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        byte[] mac = null;
        try {
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> ifaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
            while (mac == null && ifaces.hasMoreElements()) {
                mac = ifaces.nextElement().getHardwareAddress();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Ignore.
        }
        if (mac == null) {
            mac = DEFAULT_MAC;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            iv[i] = (byte) (time >> (i * 8));
        }
        System.arraycopy(mac, 0, iv, 8, mac.length);
        digestRandomBytes(iv, 256);
        return iv;
    }


    /**
     * Generates an AES key starting with an IV and applying the supplied user password.
     * <p>
     * This AES key is used to crypt IV 2 and AES key 2.
     * @param iv
     * @param password
     * @return AES key of {@link #KEY_SIZE} bytes.
     */
    protected byte[] generateAESKey1(byte[] iv, byte[] password) {
        byte[] aesKey = new byte[KEY_SIZE];
        System.arraycopy(iv, 0, aesKey, 0, iv.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < 8192; i++) {
            digest.reset();
            digest.update(aesKey);
            digest.update(password);
            aesKey = digest.digest();
        }
        return aesKey;
    }


    /**
     * Generates the random IV used to crypt file contents.
     * @return IV 2.
     */
    protected byte[] generateIV2() {
        byte[] iv = generateRandomBytes(BLOCK_SIZE);
        digestRandomBytes(iv, 256);
        return iv;
    }


    /**
     * Generates the random AES key used to crypt file contents.
     * @return AES key of {@link #KEY_SIZE} bytes.
     */
    protected byte[] generateAESKey2() {
        byte[] aesKey = generateRandomBytes(KEY_SIZE);
        digestRandomBytes(aesKey, 32);
        return aesKey;
    }


    /**
     * Utility method to read bytes from a stream until the given array is fully filled.
     * @param in
     * @param bytes
     * @throws IOException if the array can't be filled.
     */
    protected void readBytes(InputStream in, byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
        if (in.read(bytes) != bytes.length) {
            throw new IOException("Unexpected end of file");
        }
    }


    /**************
     * PUBLIC METHODS *
     **************/


    /**
     * Builds an object to encrypt or decrypt files with the given password.
     * @param password
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException if the platform does not support the required cryptographic methods.
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException if UTF-16 encoding is not supported.
     */
    public AESCrypt(String password) throws GeneralSecurityException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        this(false, password);
    }


    /**
     * Builds an object to encrypt or decrypt files with the given password.
     * @param debug
     * @param password
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException if the platform does not support the required cryptographic methods.
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException if UTF-16 encoding is not supported.
     */
    public AESCrypt(boolean debug, String password) throws GeneralSecurityException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        try {
            DEBUG = debug;
            setPassword(password);
            random = SecureRandom.getInstance(RANDOM_ALG);
            digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(DIGEST_ALG);
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CRYPT_TRANS);
            hmac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_ALG);
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new GeneralSecurityException(JCE_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE, e);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Changes the password this object uses to encrypt and decrypt.
     * @param password
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException if UTF-16 encoding is not supported.
     */
    public void setPassword(String password) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        this.password = password.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
        debug("Using password: ", this.password);
    }


    /**
     * The file at <tt>fromPath</tt> is encrypted and saved at <tt>toPath</tt> location.
     * <p>
     * <tt>version</tt> can be either 1 or 2.
     * @param version
     * @param fromPath
     * @param toPath
     * @throws IOException when there are I/O errors.
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException if the platform does not support the required cryptographic methods.
     */
    public void encrypt(int version, String fromPath, String toPath)
    throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fromPath));
            debug("Opened for reading: " + fromPath);
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(toPath));
            debug("Opened for writing: " + toPath);

            encrypt(version, in, out);
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }           
        }
    }

    /**
     * The input stream is encrypted and saved to the output stream.
     * <p>
     * <tt>version</tt> can be either 1 or 2.<br>
     * None of the streams are closed.
     * @param version
     * @param in
     * @param out
     * @throws IOException when there are I/O errors.
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException if the platform does not support the required cryptographic methods.
     */
    public void encrypt(int version, InputStream in, OutputStream out)
    throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        try {
            byte[] text = null;

            ivSpec1 = new IvParameterSpec(generateIv1());
            aesKey1 = new SecretKeySpec(generateAESKey1(ivSpec1.getIV(), password), CRYPT_ALG);
            ivSpec2 = new IvParameterSpec(generateIV2());
            aesKey2 = new SecretKeySpec(generateAESKey2(), CRYPT_ALG);
            debug("IV1: ", ivSpec1.getIV());
            debug("AES1: ", aesKey1.getEncoded());
            debug("IV2: ", ivSpec2.getIV());
            debug("AES2: ", aesKey2.getEncoded());

            out.write("AES".getBytes("UTF-8")); // Heading.
            out.write(version); // Version.
            out.write(0);   // Reserved.
            if (version == 2) { // No extensions.
                out.write(0);
                out.write(0);
            }
            out.write(ivSpec1.getIV()); // Initialization Vector.

            text = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE + KEY_SIZE];
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey1, ivSpec1);
            cipher.update(ivSpec2.getIV(), 0, BLOCK_SIZE, text);
            cipher.doFinal(aesKey2.getEncoded(), 0, KEY_SIZE, text, BLOCK_SIZE);
            out.write(text);    // Crypted IV and key.
            debug("IV2 + AES2 ciphertext: ", text);

            hmac.init(new SecretKeySpec(aesKey1.getEncoded(), HMAC_ALG));
            text = hmac.doFinal(text);
            out.write(text);    // HMAC from previous cyphertext.
            debug("HMAC1: ", text);

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey2, ivSpec2);
            hmac.init(new SecretKeySpec(aesKey2.getEncoded(), HMAC_ALG));
            text = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
            int len, last = 0;
            while ((len = in.read(text)) > 0) {
                cipher.update(text, 0, BLOCK_SIZE, text);
                hmac.update(text);
                out.write(text);    // Crypted file data block.
                last = len;
            }
            last &= 0x0f;
            out.write(last);    // Last block size mod 16.
            debug("Last block size mod 16: " + last);

            text = hmac.doFinal();
            out.write(text);    // HMAC from previous cyphertext.
            debug("HMAC2: ", text);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            throw new GeneralSecurityException(JCE_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE, e);
        }
    }


    /**
     * The file at <tt>fromPath</tt> is decrypted and saved at <tt>toPath</tt> location.
     * <p>
     * The input file can be encrypted using version 1 or 2 of aescrypt.<br>
     * @param fromPath
     * @param toPath
     * @throws IOException when there are I/O errors.
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException if the platform does not support the required cryptographic methods.
     */
    public void decrypt(String fromPath, String toPath)
    throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fromPath));
            debug("Opened for reading: " + fromPath);
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(toPath));
            debug("Opened for writing: " + toPath);

            decrypt(new File(fromPath).length(), in, out);
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        }
    }   


    /**
     * The input stream is decrypted and saved to the output stream.
     * <p>
     * The input file size is needed in advance.<br>
     * The input stream can be encrypted using version 1 or 2 of aescrypt.<br>
     * None of the streams are closed.
     * @param inSize
     * @param in
     * @param out
     * @throws IOException when there are I/O errors.
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException if the platform does not support the required cryptographic methods.
     */
    public void decrypt(long inSize, InputStream in, OutputStream out)
    throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        try {
            byte[] text = null, backup = null;
            long total = 3 + 1 + 1 + BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_SIZE + KEY_SIZE + SHA_SIZE + 1 + SHA_SIZE;
            int version;

            text = new byte[3];
            readBytes(in, text);    // Heading.
            if (!new String(text, "UTF-8").equals("AES")) {
                throw new IOException("Invalid file header");
            }

            version = in.read();    // Version.
            if (version < 1 || version > 2) {
                throw new IOException("Unsupported version number: " + version);
            }
            debug("Version: " + version);

            in.read();  // Reserved.

            if (version == 2) { // Extensions.
                text = new byte[2];
                int len;
                do {
                    readBytes(in, text);
                    len = ((0xff & (int) text[0]) << 8) | (0xff & (int) text[1]);
                    if (in.skip(len) != len) {
                        throw new IOException("Unexpected end of extension");
                    }
                    total += 2 + len;
                    debug("Skipped extension sized: " + len);
                } while (len != 0);
            }

            text = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
            readBytes(in, text);    // Initialization Vector.
            ivSpec1 = new IvParameterSpec(text);
            aesKey1 = new SecretKeySpec(generateAESKey1(ivSpec1.getIV(), password), CRYPT_ALG);
            debug("IV1: ", ivSpec1.getIV());
            debug("AES1: ", aesKey1.getEncoded());

            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey1, ivSpec1);
            backup = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE + KEY_SIZE];
            readBytes(in, backup);  // IV and key to decrypt file contents.
            debug("IV2 + AES2 ciphertext: ", backup);
            text = cipher.doFinal(backup);
            ivSpec2 = new IvParameterSpec(text, 0, BLOCK_SIZE);
            aesKey2 = new SecretKeySpec(text, BLOCK_SIZE, KEY_SIZE, CRYPT_ALG);
            debug("IV2: ", ivSpec2.getIV());
            debug("AES2: ", aesKey2.getEncoded());

            hmac.init(new SecretKeySpec(aesKey1.getEncoded(), HMAC_ALG));
            backup = hmac.doFinal(backup);
            text = new byte[SHA_SIZE];
            readBytes(in, text);    // HMAC and authenticity test.
            if (!Arrays.equals(backup, text)) {
                throw new IOException("Message has been altered or password incorrect");
            }
            debug("HMAC1: ", text);

            total = inSize - total; // Payload size.
            if (total % BLOCK_SIZE != 0) {
                throw new IOException("Input file is corrupt");
            }
            if (total == 0) {   // Hack: empty files won't enter block-processing for-loop below. 
                in.read();  // Skip last block size mod 16.
            }
            debug("Payload size: " + total);

            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey2, ivSpec2);
            hmac.init(new SecretKeySpec(aesKey2.getEncoded(), HMAC_ALG));
            backup = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
            text = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
            for (int block = (int) (total / BLOCK_SIZE); block > 0; block--) {
                int len = BLOCK_SIZE;
                if (in.read(backup, 0, len) != len) {   // Cyphertext block.
                    throw new IOException("Unexpected end of file contents");
                }
                cipher.update(backup, 0, len, text);
                hmac.update(backup, 0, len);
                if (block == 1) {
                    int last = in.read();   // Last block size mod 16.
                    debug("Last block size mod 16: " + last);
                    len = (last > 0 ? last : BLOCK_SIZE);
                }
                out.write(text, 0, len);
            }
            out.write(cipher.doFinal());

            backup = hmac.doFinal();
            text = new byte[SHA_SIZE];
            readBytes(in, text);    // HMAC and authenticity test.
            if (!Arrays.equals(backup, text)) {
                throw new IOException("Message has been altered or password incorrect");
            }
            debug("HMAC2: ", text);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            throw new GeneralSecurityException(JCE_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE, e);
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: My guess is we'd need to see you encryption/decryption code.

Comment: @AndrewBarber http://pastebin.com/kpj0nNVq I am using input stream method

Comment: Post the relevant code in your question, not in pastebin. And fix your IO: InputStream.read() doesn't necessarily read everything you ask it to read. Also, you should use session.get() to get an entity by ID, instezd of using a criteria query.

Comment: Please note that that library does not use a vetted password based key derivation method, nor does it seem to use a salt. Furthermore, even the author does acknowledge some errors in the protocol. It does not *look* fully broken broken, but it lacks security in some departments.

Comment: @owlstead can you suggest any better library than this that I can use.

Comment: JNCrypt would come to mind. You could also use a well known format like Cryptographic Message Syntax (CMS) but that takes a bit more getting used to.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it. This code was triggering the exception.

```
total = inSize - total; // Payload size.
   if (total % BLOCK_SIZE != 0) {
      throw new IOException("Input file is corrupt");
   }
```

Apparently I was passing the inSize parameter as file size but after encryption the file size increases by roughly about 134 bytes. So that modulus doesn't come out zero. I have checked the original, encrypted, the data that was passed to hibernate and the data that hibernate returns there is no single point of conflict. The hibernate returns the same byte data when I retrieve it using `get or criteria` that was passed at the time of saving into database.
Hope this helps others who are trying to use AES encryption and decryption along with hibernate.